# How to save my listview data and read again while my application pause or resume

Tags: android, eclipse, listactivity

This is my code.I am studing a simple budget calculater application.My only purpose is how much I spend seeing in one mount ? But when I closed my application or pressed the back button on my telephone , I lost all my items. How can I fix this problem ?

```
 public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    private static final String[] items={"31.03.2017 Harcama ve Kazanç Tablosu"};
    public static final int MENU_ADD = Menu.FIRST+1;
    String ilk = "31.03.2017 Harcama ve Kazanç Tablosu";
    public static final int MENU_RESET = Menu.FIRST+2;
    public static final int MENU_REMOVE = Menu.FIRST+4 ;
     ArrayList<String> words=null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState ) {
    super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState );

    initadapter();
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());

    }

    private void initadapter() {
        words=new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String s : items) {
        words.add(s);
        }
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, words));// TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
    ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_ADD, Menu.NONE, "Ekle");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_REMOVE, Menu.NONE, "Sil");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info= (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=(ArrayAdapter<String>)getListAdapter();
     {  
    }
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case MENU_REMOVE:
    adapter.remove(words.get(info.position));
    case MENU_ADD:
    add();
    return(true);
    }
    return(super.onContextItemSelected(item));
    }{
    }
    private void add() {

    final View addView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Gider veya gelir ekle.")
    .setView(addView)
    .setPositiveButton("Tamam",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
    int whichButton) {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=(ArrayAdapter<String>)getListAdapter();
    EditText yazı=(EditText)addView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    adapter.add(yazı.getText().toString());
    }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Geri", null)
    .show();

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways to save data from your application.
I suggest you take a look at the developer guidelines [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html) first.

Shared Preferences is the most straight-forward approach with their Key-Value sets, especially for simple applications.

You usually can save the data you need in the onPause() method and load it back into the activity next time it is launched.

Comment: I knew shared preference and onPause() methods.I searched my books.(and thanks for this new developer guidelines link) but When I was tried shared preference , my application saved twice items.Then, again all data has gone. I know I should use the onPause() method.Unfortunately, I did not.

Comment: @BerkayIşıkoğlu the duplicates in your saved preferences really depend on your code logic. If you are saving just the string of each item, a simple for loop in which you add each entry to your prefs should do the job. And onPause() -> save, onCreate() -> load is the way to go in this case.

Comment: I am trying 3 days on this project . I guess onPause() method it should be like that : protected void onPause() {  for(String a : items){  SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("Kelimeler",MODE_PRIVATE); SharedPreferences.Editor edit = shared.edit(); edit.putString("itemler" , a);edit.commit();} super.onPause();} But when I run this code and load to words array adapter , my telefone only saved one word. It is not loading another words.

Comment: @BerkayIşıkoğlu the onPause looks wrong, you should first create the shared preferences instance, then start the for loop to put your string in, and finally commit outside the loop.